# Keras backend Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have to design a keras model that take RGB as input and produce RGB output. I have to design three parrallel layers for R,G,and B as shown in the image.

[image: Keras Model]

Now my question is how to split RGB image into R,G, B and give as input to three parallel layers of CNN. Can anybody help me please

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.utils import plot_model
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input, concatenate,  
ZeroPadding2D, merge, add
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import optimizers
from keras import losses
from keras.optimizers import SGD, Adam
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
visible = Input(shape=(64,64,3))

R = visible[:][:][:][0]
G = visible[:][:][:][1]
B = visible[:][:][:][2]

#red, green, blue = tf.split(3, 3, visible)
# first feature extractor

#conv1_1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
#kernel_initializer='he_normal')(visible)
conv1_1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
kernel_initializer='he_normal')(R)
conv1_1 = Activation('relu')(conv1_1)

conv2_1 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1_1)
conv2_1 = Activation('relu')(conv2_1)

conv3_1= Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2_1)
conv3_1 = Activation('relu')(conv3_1)

#conv1_2 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
#kernel_initializer='he_normal')(visible)
conv1_2 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
kernel_initializer='he_normal')(G)
conv1_2 = Activation('relu')(conv1_2)

conv2_2 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1_2)
conv2_2 = Activation('relu')(conv2_2)

conv3_2= Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2_2)
conv3_2 = Activation('relu')(conv3_2)

#conv1_3 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
#kernel_initializer='he_normal')(visible)
conv1_3 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
kernel_initializer='he_normal')(B)
conv1_3 = Activation('relu')(conv1_3)

conv2_3 = Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv1_3)
conv2_3 = Activation('relu')(conv2_3)

conv3_3= Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', 
kernel_initializer='he_normal')(conv2_3)
conv3_3 = Activation('relu')(conv3_3)


merge = concatenate([conv3_1, conv3_2, conv3_3])

model = Model(inputs=visible, outputs=merge)
# summarize layers
print(model.summary())
# plot graph
plot_model(model, to_file='shared_input_layer.png')
```

I want to split 'Visible' into R, G, B and give as input to conv1_1, conv1_2, and conv1_3. I want to add layer to split RGB and give as input automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the three nets are different:

```
visible = Input((64,64,3))

RGB = Lambda(lambda x: tf.split(x, 3, axis=-1))(visible)

net1 = Conv2D(....)(RGB[0])
net1 = Activation(....)(net1)
net1 = Conv2D(....)(net1)
net1 = Activatoin(....)(net1)

net2 = Conv2D(....)(RGB[1])
....

net3 = Conv2D(....)(RGB[2])
.....

joined = Concatenate()([net1,net2,net3])

model = Model(visible, joined)
```

If the three nets are the same:

```
visible = Input((64,64,3))

out = Lambda(lambda x: K.permute_dimensions(x,(0,3,1,2)))(visible)
out = Reshape((3,64,64,1))(out)

out = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(...))(out)
out = TimeDistributed(Activation(...))(out)
out = TimeDistributed(Conv2D(...))(out)
....

out = Reshape((3,64,64))(out)
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.permute_dimensions(x, (0,2,3,1)))(out)

model = Model(visible,out)
```

Comment: Yes it solve my problem... is it is possible to combine the output of three network in similar way like the spliting using Lambda layer ???. I combine using the concatenation function.

Comment: It is. But the concatenation is easier to use. A `Lambda` layer is just a custom layer that can use any function you want.

Answer (score 0):

For multi-input, multi-output models use functional api: https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/

For merging results of your conv layers you can use keras' concatenate layer. https://keras.io/layers/merge/#concatenate

```
imgs, y = read_data()
R = imgs[:][:][:][0]
G = imgs[:][:][:][1]
B = imgs[:][:][:][2]
model.fit([R,G,B], y, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks but R, G, and B are still 3 dimensional.                                                    >>> visible = Input(shape=(64,64,3))
>>> R = visible[:][:][:][0]
>>> R.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(64), Dimension(64), Dimension(3)])
>>>

Answer (score 0):

When you input an RGB image to your model, you're actually inputting a tensor of size `(height ,width ,3)` where  `3` represents the 3 channels ( red, green, yellow)

[image]

You can separate the channels by :

```
b, g, r    = image_array[:, :, 0], image_array[:, :, 1], image_array[:, :, 2]
```

just make sure that your channels are aligned correctly ( be careful to remove the alpha channel if it exists)

Also you can use [OpenCV](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which will make it much easier to deal with images

```
import cv2
b, g, r    = cv2.split(image_array)
```